# Communication between components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

On my Angular 8 project, I defined a function in `projects.component.ts` that I would like to use in `update.component.ts`. I know how to import this function in `update.component.ts`, all's fine there.
The problem is that we need, at some point, to change a function, because the reloading function is not the same in `projects.component.ts` and `update.component.ts`.
So what I need to do is to trigger a function in `update.component.ts` at some point in the `projects.component.ts`' function.
Here's the code of the function I want to use :

```js
hrProjectArchiveDel(projectId) {
     this.loading = true;
     const body = {   
       "projectId": projectId
     };

     Swal.fire({
       title: 'Supprimer/Archiver ?',
       text: "Voulez-vous supprimer (ou archiver) ce projet ? Pour qu'il soit effectivement supprimé, il ne doit plus contenir de sous-projet, et aucune activité ni pointage ne doit avoir eu lieu dessus.",
       type: 'warning',
       showCancelButton: true,
       confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
       cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
       confirmButtonText: 'Oui, Supprimer/Archiver !',
       cancelButtonText: 'Non, Annuler',
       reverseButtons: true
     }).then((result) => {
       if (result.value) {
         this.http.post('hr/point/hrPointageProjectsArchiveDelete', body).subscribe(
         data => {
            this.reloadProjects(); //!!! This is the function that should change !!!
            this.loading = false;

            if (data[0].deleted_row_count==1) {
              Swal.fire(
                'Supprimé !',
                'Le projet était vide, et a donc été supprimé.',
                'success'
              );
            } else {
              Swal.fire(
                'Archivé !',
                'Le projet n\'était pas vide ou a été utilisé, et a donc été simplement archivé.',
                'success'
              );

            }

           },
           (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
             location.reload();
           }
         );
       } else {
         this.loading = false;
       }
     })
  }
```

The function is imported as follows :

```js
import {ProjectsComponent} from '../../projects/projects.component';
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {
   projectsref: ProjectsComponent;
   constructor(private http: HttpClient, public authentificationService: AuthentificationService){
   this.projectsref = new ProjectsComponent(http, authentificationService);
   }
}
```

And used as follows (the tag is closed later) :

```html
<button *ngIf="hrProject.Type=='P'" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="projectsref.hrProjectArchiveDel(hrProject.id)">
```

And here's the tree of my components :
[Components' tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8x6.png)

Sorry for not being able to create a Stackblitz, but I still hope you'll be able to help me :)
(I'm still here if you need additionnal informations)
Zirion

Comment: Please, don't attach photos. Add some relevant code so we can better figure out how to help you.

Comment: You could use an `abstract` class in order to have more classes with the same definition of the method. In order to call a function in component A from component B you could use a `Subject`.

Comment: Isn't it possible just by modifying existing files ?

Comment: This doesn't look like Angular at all. instantiating a Component inside a Component is not what you want to do at all. Make a Service, put the code there and inject it in both components.

Comment: @Carsten This way, will I be able to change what is inside the function in the components ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'change what is inside the function'? A function is what it is, it's behaviour can change by altering parameters. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. What is clear is that you're using Angular wrong.

Comment: My friend suggested me to emit an event in the function so a listener runs the `update.component.ts`' reload at this precise time. Would it be a bad idea ?